# MSBuild Change config value based on debug / release build

Tags: msbuild

In my app.config, I have

```
<endpoint address="http://debug.example.com/Endpoint.asmx" stuff />
```

How can I modify the build tasks so that when I do a release build it changes the endpoint address to

```
<endpoint address="http://live.example.com/Endpoint.asmx" stuff />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [MSBuild extension pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/) the Xml task will allow you to change an entry in an XML file. Import the custom tasks in your MSBuild file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" />
```

and update an XML value:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <OldValue>http://debug.example.com/Endpoint.asmx</OldValue>
   <NewValue>http://live.example.com/Endpoint.asmx</NewValue>
</PropertyGroup>

<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Xml.XmlFile 
    TaskAction="UpdateAttribute" 
    File="app.config" 
    XPath="/configuration/system.serviceModel/client/endpoint[@address='$(OldValue)']" 
    Key="address"
    Value="$(NewValue)"
/>
```

Substitute your XPath and only execute this during a release build using Condition .

Answer (score 4):

If your debug/release configurations are named Debug and Release respectively, this should do it:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
  <endpoint address="http://debug.example.com/Endpoint.asmx" stuff />
  <!-- other things depending on Debug Configuration can go here -->
</PropertGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <endpoint address="http://live.example.com/Endpoint.asmx" stuff />
</PropertGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS 2012 or above, you can add a config transform to replace the values on build. If you're using 2010 this is available for web.config automatically, but for app.configs you'll need to do a slight hack on your *.csproj file outlined here: 
http://www.andrewdenhertog.com/msbuild/setting-web-app-settings-configuration-transforms-ducks-nuts-msbuild-part-8/